# Delphi XE4 FireMonkey/iOS DrawBitmap not working

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

So through my routine I have calculated new width/height I want for my TBitmap (**ABitmap**) shown inside a TImage.

Here's the code that resize and draw **ABitmap**

```
var
  TmpScale: Double;
  TmpNH: Single;
  TmpNW: Single;
  P: string;
begin      
  P := FAppDataDirPath + 'Library' + PathDelim + 'assets' + PathDelim + 'app_header.png';
  if FileExists(P) then
    begin
      ImageLogo.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(1,1);
      ImageLogo.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(P);

      TmpScale := ImageLogo.Width / ImageLogo.Bitmap.Width;
      TmpNW := ImageLogo.Bitmap.Width * TmpScale;
      TmpNH := ImageLogo.Bitmap.Height * TmpScale;

      FBitmapBuffer.Width := Round(TmpNW);
      FBitmapBuffer.Height := Round(TmpNH);
      FBitmapBuffer.Canvas.DrawBitmap(ImageLogo.Bitmap, RectF(0,0,ImageLogo.Bitmap.Width,ImageLogo.Bitmap.Height), RectF(0,0,TmpNW,TmpNH), 255);
      ImageLogo.Bitmap.Assign(FBitmapBuffer);
```

All I get is a completely blank area where TImage is shown.

Comment: The documentation about [FMX.Types.TBitmap.LoadFromFile(..)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Types.TBitmap.LoadFromFile) states that the `TBitmap` object remains totally unchanged if the file could not be loaded. Furthermore, **no exception** is raised. To me, it looks like your file cannot be loaded and you're pasting your 1x1 bitmap onto your Image.

Comment: Good guess... I checked it out, but If I don't call Service_SizeImage_MaxSideKeepScale a bitmap is shown.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful I have updated the code now, so the example is complete

Comment: I should probably be able to tell from your code, but can you please tell what Delphi/FireMonkey Version you're using?

Comment: Delphi XE4 with iOS mobile addon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at `TCanvas.BeginScene(..)`: Before you paint something onto the canvas, you have to *begin* the scene, and *end* it later on:

```
if yourCanvas.BeginScene() then
    try
        yourCanvas.DrawBitmap(..);
    finally
        yourCanvas.EndScene();
    end;
```

That's pretty much it: You were just missing the call to `BeginScene()` and `EndScene()`. But apart from that, I have several suggestions:

### Suggestions

1. You don't have to create a Bitmap with a bogus resolution, just to load stuff from disk. Just use the alternatative constructor `TBitmap.CreateFromFile(const AFileName: string)`.
2. You also need to make sure that FBitmapBuffer points to a valid `TBitmap` object. You should insert a check like `if not Assigned(FBitmapBuffer) then FBitmapBuffer := TBitmap.Create(..);`
3. Furthermore, you're creating a new TBitmap object everytime and you're not freeing it after your work is done. Everytime you call your procedure, your memory gets filled up with TBitmaps you're never going to see again. You should free it at the end of your procedure.
4. Also, are you sure that, for example, setting the width of your new bitmap to `Round(TmpNW)` is what you want? I guess you were meant to type `Trunc(TmpNW)` instead.
5. Why are you using the bitmap of your firemonkey component to load the image from disk and not your `FBitmapBuffer` object?
6. Finally: Altough we got the pasting of the bitmap onto the `TImage` working now, I honestly have no clue what you were trying to do in the first place. Paste the bitmap onto an Image while keeping the aspect ratio? A `TiImage` has a `WrapMode` property that let's you set how it's image is going to be scaled.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help: 1) ok, 2) It is valid. 3) FBitmapBuffer is reused, hence not freed 4) Round appars to me to be more precise than Trunch? 5) FBitmapBuffer is used temporary to get the fixed/correctly sized/scaled bitmap 6) It is not working even with begin/end scene, unfortunately. The TImage does not show the bitmap. Anyhow, to answer your question, I want to control the scaling myself when loading images because I am not happy with the modes supported. I want optimal sizing to *selected* side, scaled correctly. And I walso want this working if the bitmap is *smaller* than TImage.

Comment: Another problem was I during testing had switched back to using "0" for opacity. I had already tried with "255" of course whjich my original example also shows. But when I initially tested your solution (marked as accepted) it did not work because of that :)

Comment: To avoid further confusion, have a look at the property [TControl.Opacity](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Types.TControl.Opacity): " If Opacity is 1, the control is completely opaque; if it is 0, the control is completely transparent.". Also, did you get it working, or not? If not, why did you accept it as an answer then? If not, please unaccept it and I will make a new, more Elaborate answer :-)

Comment: Also, I'm still not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Just a new scaling mode that upscales small Bitmaps? Or something like the Windows wallpaper Setting 'Fill' or 'Fit'?

Comment: Thanks for details on opacity. And yes it is working now. Yes, scaling modes for small bitmaps so they e.g. fill (proportionally) optimally in width, height or both to dimensions (often larger than the bitmap) determined runtime.